# How do I call a Cake file from a Rake file, or a Make file, or some combination of these?

Tags: ruby, makefile, rake, coffeescript, cakephp

So, I have a cake file for building my Coffeescript (thanks to https://github.com/krismolendyke/InstantJasmineCoffee). I also have a directory full of SCSS based on Compass, which I call with a quick "compass compile," which comes from a Ruby gem.

Is there a way to call "compass compile" from within my Cake file, or a way to call my Cake file from within a Rake file, or a Make file that can do both, or something else entirely? What's the easiest way to do all of my compilations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

radiospiel has shown how you could run `compass` or `cake` from a `Rake` file. To call `compass` or `rake` from a `Cakefile`, you'd write something like this:

```
{exec} = require 'child_process'
exec 'compass compile'
```

(Replace `compass compile` with whatever system command you want to run.) Note that this would, by default, suppress the output from the command; you should probably use a callback to log that output. See the Node docs on [child_process.exec](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec) for details.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, the problem wasn't running compass or cake from Rake; that I could do. What I was looking for was exec from within Cake. I have no idea how I failed to see that in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

As a Rakefile is just ruby source, you can use `system`, eg.

```
description "Compile"
task :compile do
    system "compass compile"
end
```

Comment: Right, but how do I get my Cake stuff in there?

Comment: Didn't you write that "compass compile" is what compiles your stuff? Well, then this is the way to go... but it seems I don't understand your issues completely.

Comment: I think radiospiel's got it. Just replace `compass compile` with `cake compile`, or whatever else you want to run on the command line.

Comment: Ok, I was misunderstanding a bit. I wasn't realizing that "system" was doing what I was after. Thanks for the response; can't mark two as answers, so have more upvotes.